# How to set the file path for fileInputStream in eclipse

Tags: java, deserialization

I have created Student Object and serialized and now I want to deserialize it.But I was confused how to give file path in working with eclipse

```
    ObjectInputStream ob = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("f.txt"));
    Student s=(Student)ob.readObject();  
    ob.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the location of the file relative to the root of the project.

For example if you have the file stored in

```
YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/package_name/file.txt
```

you need to use

```
new FileInputStream("package_name/file.txt")
```

Else you can also specify the absolute path.
Something like

```
new FileInputStream("C:/Users/admin/workspace/YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/...../file.txt")
```

Comment: Did it solve your problem @chamina? If yes please accept the solution.